# symlink created not responding to file content change

Tags: git, symlink

I just created a hook under the hooks directory directly under my local repo and tried to symlink it to corresponding hook in the .git/hooks directory.

I executed following command in the git bash terminal(I am doing all this on Windows 10) :

`ln -s -f ../../hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/commit-msg`

Running the above command does not seem to create symlink. All it does is just create a copy of the original file under **.git/hooks/**

The reason I say this is because, I confirmed that changing the content of original file doesn't change the symlink's content.

Generally, when we create a symlink of any file on windows, it looks like a shortcut icon and any change is refled in the other file, but in my case the created symlink(**.git/hooks/commit-msg**) looks like any normal file icon.

I tried deleting the **.git/hooks/commit-msg symlink** and running the command again and found that the command does create the file under **.git/hooks/**, but as I said earlier, its just like a normal copy of original file and not appears/behaves like a symlink.

Please guide me. I am just not able to understand this weird behavior.

Comment: Did you enable symlink support when you set up Git for Windows?  If not, reinstall and enable it.

Comment: @bk2204 Yes, as far as remember, I did enable the symlink option while installing git. I had a project where I was required to test the symlinks. So I beliee it is enabled. But, is there any way to check if the symlink support is enabled in my currently installed git instance, without the need of reinstalling it and checking the box?

Comment: Verified via git config --list command , it lists core.symlinks=true, so I believe this confirms that symlinks support is enabled